# Thousands of user registrations advice

Tags: users

Bit of a generalist question but in case someone has anything to share... I am thinking of building a campaign site in Craft that will register 15,000+ users. Is there anything I should be aware of or pay particular attention to?

The users will have a front end registration and a dozen custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

I would also think about spam bot registrations, which can be a big problem, and the more popular your site, the more attempts you're likely to see.

I'd add something like Google recaptcha to avoid that...we use this: https://github.com/aberkie/craft-recaptcha - and have had zero spam registrations since launch.

With our old site we used to get them all the time (not Craft but a form is a form, so that doesn't really matter I think!)

Answer (score 0):

Should be easily doable, with the usual caveats of make sure you've planned hardware/resources wise.  i.e. if you expect 15k users to all register over a 3 hour period, you'll want to make sure you're able to scale to meet those resources requirements.

The CP in Craft 2 will start to show some performance/scaling issues on things like the Users index page once you start to reach the several hundred thousand user mark (again depending on hardware and resources depends on exactly how many).  That's one of the big areas we've addressed in Craft 3 as well.

Comment: Thx for reassurance. I think it will be 20 K tops over a few weeks on our dedicated server with nginx as proxy to apache. Having said that don't want to cache logged in users form interactions.......